imperfect subjunctive expressing pluperfect progressive tense?
We know that occasionally the Latin imperfect indicative is used for what we in English would express as a pluperfect progressive:
  Et illis, quod iam diu cupiebant, novandi res occasio data est (Livy 24.29.3).
  And to the former an opportunity for a change was given that they had been long desiring.
 Multosque per annos/Errabant acti fatis maria omnia circum (Virgil Æn. I.32-3).
  And for many years they had been wandering, driven by the Fates, around all the seas.
Can anybody provide examples of the imperfect as pluperfect continuous in the conjunctive? If not, any examples of another tense (the simple pluperfect?) or tenses with a pluperfect progressive sense?

Woodcock (#200) cites Cicero: Labebar longius, nisi me retinuissem , "I was slipping further, had I not caught myself up". Caecina delapsu circumveniebant, ni prima legio sese opposuisset, "Caecina fell and was in a wayto be surrounded, had not the first legion interposed itself." If these are what you are looking for, I can post them (and some others) as an answer.

@Figulus Thanks—that's not quite what I'm after—I'm looking to see whether it would be possible to say (to take your examples) "blah blah blah, quippe qui laberer, nisi me retinuissem" or "blah blah blah, quod circumvenīrent, ni prima legio," etc. I asked this question long enough ago that I no longer remember what prompted it.
